# How can I make a function in google sheet run on all the previous cells above until the previous function

Tags: google-sheets, sum, google-sheets-formula

I want to make a function in google sheet, for example here "sum" I want it sum all above cells until the previous another function
So if I copied it to another row it will sum all above cell until the previous function also (3 of pic).

[image]

Comment: Why do you begin the sum at row#15 in your example?

Comment: Why is there no checkbox in B7? that will help to determine the beginning of te sum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try these custom functions

```
// mike steelson
function sumSinceLastFormula(rng){
  var lastRow = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange().getRow()-1
  var col = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange().getColumn()
  var sum=0
  for (var i = lastRow; i>1; i--){
    var value = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getRange(i,col).getFormula()
    if (value && value.toString().charAt(0) === '=') {break}
    else {sum += SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getRange(i,col).getValue()}
  }
  return sum
}
function countaSinceLastFormula(rng){
  var lastRow = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange().getRow()-1
  var col = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange().getColumn()
  var counta=0
  for (var i = lastRow; i>1; i--){
    var value = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getRange(i,col).getFormula()
    if (value && value.toString().charAt(0) === '=') {break}
    else {counta++}
  }
  return counta
}
function countifSinceLastFormula(rng,crit){
  var lastRow = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange().getRow()-1
  var col = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange().getColumn()
  var countif=0
  for (var i = lastRow; i>1; i--){
    var value = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getRange(i,col).getFormula()
    if (value && value.toString().charAt(0) === '=') {break}
    else {if (SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getRange(i,col).getValue()==crit) {countif++} }
  }
  return countif
}
```

to automatically update the values, add reference to previous cells

```
=sumSinceLastFormula(F$2:F8)
```

when in F9, and copy where you need it.

[image]
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1iXDbYDd_5rmHa1E41zobTWB6MKvABR1ERpCgcValIng/copy

Comment: Thank you, that was a great job, but is there any method to do like that with this function 
=COUNTIF(D10:D20,"*NEW" )
in this case I want it like sum, countif for all above values, but will stop when find the previous function, because of I will repeated it more than time in this column

Comment: ok i focused on SUM, but i can duplicate the process for COUNT and COUNTIF, I will do it soon ...

Comment: I have completed my answer and the attached spreadsheet.

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate the cumulative by a single formula like

```
={"sum";arrayformula(SUMIF(ROW(A2:A),"<="&ROW(A2:A),F2:F))}
```

[image]

Comment: I'm so sorry, but I guess you didn't catch what I mean.
I need make a "sum" function but with a condition>> it will sum all above values in the same column but when it face another function it stop.

Comment: yes, I understood correctly, but I would like to propose another approach!

Comment: I'll try to be more clear, I made checkboxes in the left for running macro >> will do that 
macro will copy the sum function in F7 to more than place in F coloumn, but the problem is 
the sum function in F7 just calculate the 5 cells above, 
when I copy it in another place in F column I want it to calculate all above values but will stop when find the previous Sum function because of I will repeated it more than time in this column

Comment: ok, I will try to do it with `ISFORMULA `